# Raspberry Pi/Raspbian: Trying to mount router hard drive

Tags: linux, debian, mount, raspberry-pi, cifs

Linux/raspberry pi noob here. 
I'm trying to mount a hard drive that's connected to my router (ip: 192.168.0.1).

I can find and explore it through the file explorer through Go > Network and it shows me its path: `smb://nas/volume%28sda1%29`

using smbclient -L it gives me the following:

```
sudo smbclient -L //192.168.0.1/volume%28sda1%29
```

WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter root's password:
    Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.14a]

```
        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        volume(sda1)    Disk
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (NAS)
        ADMIN$          IPC       IPC Service (NAS)
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.14a]

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------
        DESKTOP-KRB4NFM
        DESKTOP-ROBIN
        NAS                  NAS

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
        WORKGROUP            NAS
```

But when i run the command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o //192.168.0.1/volume%28sda1%29 /media/HDD
```

it returns:

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I am completely clueless how to proceed.

A thing of note is that it prompts me for a password, yet there is none and it works through the file explorer without one.

Many thanks in advance,

Raaabiiin

Comment: Try using the unexpanded name `sudo mount -t cifs -o '//192.168.0.1/volume(sda1)' /media/HDD`.

Comment: Hey @AFH
I get the following response:

mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Comment: I think we have progressed - I am pretty sure `'//192.168.0.1/volume(sda1)' is the correct parameter. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427044/mounting-cifs-drive-gives-mount-error22-invalid-argument/665802) may help, or other results from searching for "cifs mount error 22". Is the drive connected to an Ethernet port or an in-built USB port on the router? I'm not rure how this would affect things, but I could do some tests on the USB port on my own router, if this is relevant. I have no problems connecting with Ethernet (NAS) drives from Ubuntu.

Comment: Followed your link and it gives me the resulting error through the log:

raspberrypi kernel: [101608.797158] CIFS: Unknown mount option "                             //192.168.0.1/volume%28sda1%29"

Also, my hard drive is connected to my router through USB

Comment: I said to use the unexpanded (and quoted) device name `'//192.168.0.1/volume(sda1)'`. But I'll try some experiments with my router's USB port later.

Comment: Sorry, I tried both and both gave me the same result. The other one just had the unexpanded name in the error

Comment: I've just plugged a disc into one of my router's USB ports and I found that on Ubuntu Mate 16.04.3 I could just start the default File Manager (`caja`) and press `Ctrl-L` to input `smb://192.168.0.1/` and I got the single entry `volume(sda1)`. I clicked this and the volume was auto-mounted and I can happily read and write to it as a network drive on `smb://192.168.0.1/volume(sda1)/` in Caja, but I cannot see it in `df`, `mount`, `Disks`, nor in my normal auto-mount folder `/media/$USER/`, nor in `/mnt/*`. I can't see the volume properties, nor file permissions. I'll try mounting it as you did.

Comment: Success! I found the `-o` option was wrong (should be followed by options list). In `/etc/fstab` I added the line `//192.168.0.1/volume(sda1) /media/HDD cifs uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw,nounix,nocase 0 0` (`nounix,nocase` since it's a Windows disc). Now it is sufficient to use `sudo mount /media/HDD`, though you can optionally add the other parameters (except `-o`). Two restrictions remain: any form of the `mount` command always prompts `Password for root@//192.168.0.1/volume(sda1): ` (I enter new-line); and I can't access via FTP, but `df`, etc, and `bash` access are OK.

Comment: By the way, my router is a TP-Link, and I needed to make sure that its settings had all the correct sharing and access parameters. I didn't try `expect` for the mount command, but I imagine that it will solve the prompt problem. If you find that some of these commands work for you, I'll summarise the comments in an answer, to clarify it for other site users.

Comment: Hey that worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help! You rock! Happy Holidays man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion, it was established that the Samba drive was connected to a USB port on the router.

The first thing to check is that the router's parameters relating to sharing the USB drive are set appropriately. Each router will have its own dialogue for this.

I got errors on Ubuntu Mate 16.04.3 when running the `smbclient` command in the question, so I never saw the listing with `%NN` instead of `(` and `)`, which is how my router's firmware listed the drive.

Instead, I added a line to `/etc/fstab`, similar to those for my other network shares:

```
//192.168.0.1/volume(sda1) /media/HDD cifs uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,username=root,password=,rw,nounix,nocase 0 0
```

In this case `1000` is both the user and group ID for my personal account, so the entry will mount the disc to me with full read, write and execute access (`...mode=0777`); `root` with no password is the account my router uses to log on to the USB disc, and `nounix,nocase` is needed for a Windows disc.

Now I can mount and dismount the disc simply with:

```
sudo mount /media/HDD
sudo umount /media/HDD
```

These parameters can be added in different formats with the `-o` option in mount, but I am more accustomed to the `fstab` format, and it makes mounting and dismounting so much easier. Note that if boot-up performs a `mount -a`, then there will be errors logged if the disc is not connected to the router during a reboot, but this should not stop the boot process itself.

The biggest thing wrong in the question was that `mount` command included `-o` with no subsequent option string, so the network address was interpreted as the option string, making nonsense of the command; but a further problem is that `mount` does not handle the `%NN` expansions of the brackets, so the proper bracket characters are needed, which means quoting the network address to stop the shell interpreting the brackets (or escaping them individually):

```
sudo mount ... '//192.168.0.1/volume(sda1)' ...
sudo mount ... //192.168.0.1/volume\(sda1\) ...
```

Mounting in this way, I can see the drive in `df` and `mount`, and can access it from `bash` through `/media/HDD/*`, as well as having full access through the file manager (`caja` in my system), though mounting and dismounting cannot be done from here (as with my other network drives).

For some reason, I can't find the user and password for FTP access, although my router is set to enable it. I don't need this, so I shan't pursue it, as any solution would be particular to my router.

I am sure it's possible to do the same with `mount` options, instead of the `fstab` entry (which avoids the `mount -a` problem), but the options are confusingly different, and I have stuck with using `fstab`, so I am not going to debug this command in order to propose it.